# subversion commit & or add status

Tags: svn

when I go into my working directory to see if svn has picked up my changes this is what I get:

```
demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-53:www demet8$ svn status
?       portals/10091
```

It appears svn has picked it up? but when I go into the actual file to be committed I get this  msg:

```
demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-53:10091 demet8$ ls -la

total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 demet8  staff   170 Feb 18 10:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  64 demet8  staff  2176 Feb 18 18:08 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 demet8  staff  6148 Feb 18 18:11 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   6 demet8  staff   204 Feb 18 10:31 6866
drwxr-xr-x   2 demet8  staff    68 Feb 18 10:05 logs

demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-53:6866 demet8$ svn add 6866
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

*The two files im actually trying to commit are 6866. Being that I tried to commit 6866 & it failed, I tried to commit to files inside 6866 and I get this msg:

```
demet8$ svn add payment.tpl payment_return.php
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

What could I be possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you just showed us, you are not working in a checkout.  You have to actually check out the code to be in a `working copy`, like the error message is complaining about.

You need to actually do, for example, `svn co svn://my.svn.repo/my/code/trunk` and do any modifications in there.

Edit:

I didn't address the first part of your question.  The `?` doesn't mean that it picked the change up.  It means that it has no idea what it is.  From the documentation:

```
'?' item is not under version control
```

Comment: Agreed - lack of '.svn' dir in ls -la means the directory is not a working copy.